# Reference for this fact about perturbed polytopes?

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, polytopes

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a polytope (i.e., an intersection of finitely many halfspaces that has finite volume) and consider $F(K) := \int_K \|x\|^2\, {\rm d}x$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm. (This quantity arises naturally, e.g., in the study of the Slicing Conjecture.) We are interested in how $F(K)$ changes as we "tilt" a facet of $K$ slightly about the vector normal to the facet. I.e., we are interested in a transformation like this:

[image: A "tilt"]

In https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.05979 (Section 3), Oded Regev and I prove that such "tilts" of angle $O(\varepsilon)$ only change F(K) by $O(\varepsilon^2)$ if the relevant facet is symmetric about the vector normal to the facet. (We call this a "normally symmetric facet." Notice, e.g., that the top facet of $K$ in the above figure is normally symmetric, but the other facets are not. Perhaps other authors have studied this type of symmetry by a different name?) The proof is not difficult (see below for the rough idea in two dimensions), but somewhat laborious, and we were wondering if there is a reference that already contains this or a similar statement.

Below, we make this formal and sketch the proof in two dimensions.

Let $w$ be a vector defining a facet of $K$. I.e., the intersection of the boundary of $K$ with the hyperplane
$\{ x \ : \ \langle w, x \rangle = 1 \}$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional. Suppose that this facet is symmetric about $w$ (i.e., $2\pi_w(x) - x$ is in the facet if and only if $x$ is in the facet, where $\pi_w$ is projection onto the span of $w$). We claim that the perturbation $w \mapsto w + \varepsilon v$ for some vector $v$ orthogonal to $w$ only changes the value of $F(K)$ by $\pm O(\varepsilon^2)$. This perturbation is in fact a "tilt," as illustrated in this figure:

[image: Perturbing w]

Indeed, notice that the effect is $O(\varepsilon^2)$ in this two-dimensional example because (1) regions $A$ and $B$ are congruent; (2) the congruence mapping from $A$ to $B$ only changes norms by an additive $O(\varepsilon)$; (3) $A$ and $B$ have volume $O(\varepsilon)$; and (4) region $C$ has volume $O(\varepsilon^2)$.

[image: Proof sketch]

Is there a nice reference for this fact (or something similar) in $n$ dimensions? (In https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.05979, we actually need to prove a slightly stronger statement, where we perturb all facets simultaneously.)